# Searching a data from database with different formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to know, that in my data base there is a records separated with **-** mark.

As an example, **1254-KJC-21** or **12345-BB-125** like wise data saved on my data table.

But some occasions, there is an excel upload I have to do and the excel that data goes as **1254KJC21** or **12345BB125** like wise.

From the excel upload, I'm doing Qty update so I need to check excel data part no with the data already existing in the data base table and update the qty.

So is there a way to match, the excel data without **-** with the data in the data table with **-** mark?

This is the model of the Inventory

```
public class InventoryMain {
  [Key]
  public int Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
  [Display(Name = "Part Number")]
  public string PartNo {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Display(Name = "Part Description")]
  public string PartDescription {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Display(Name = "Part Model")]
  public string PartModel {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Display(Name = "Available Qty")]
  public int AvaQty {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Display(Name = "Re-Order Level")]
  public int ? ReOrderQty {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Display(Name = "Part Category")]
  public int ? PartCatogary {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Display(Name = "ABCD Category")]
  public int ? A_B_C_D_Category {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Product_Code {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public bool Status {
    get;
    set;
  } = true;
  public DateTime ? LastUpdated {
    get;
    set;
  } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

[image]
This is how looks like the data in database

This is the excel file that need to upload.
[image]

Comment: If there is a consistent unambiguous rule about where to add the `-`, then yes it is possible. Excel upload to where? a database? You should really consider cleaning the data on the way in so that the data is consistent.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it not consistent rule, there could be four digits and ``-`` then two digits or three digits and ``-``. So the easiest way I thought is getting the all Part Number data from database to list and then remove the ``-`` part from the data and then match with the data that the excel has and took the data ID and update the database record. As I planned. Is there any other way to do this? the part that removes the ``-`` is I don't know how to do it

Comment: So the `-` have no meaning - you could just remove them altogether? So  `1254-KJC-21` is the same as `1254KJC21` is the same as 12-54KJ-C21`? You're working with data. You mention a database... but you have not actually mentioned what database you are loading into.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have updated the question. ``1254-KJC-21`` in the database, excel file data would be ``1254KJC21`` only. I mean the format of some data could be ``XXXX-XXX-XXX`` some ``XXXXXX-XX`` likewise. But in the excel they all like ``XXXXXXXXX`` .

Comment: Your screendshot is SQL Server. The way I would do this is import the excel data into a staging table and use an update query. It's simple to use `replace(fieldname,'-','')` to remove all `-` symbols for the match. Are you uploading the excel data into a table?